# Error in rvest::submit_form() - object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable

Tags: r, tidyverse, rvest, httr, rlang

I'm trying to submit a form via rvest and am getting stuck on the final `submit_form()` step.

The problem is a little hard to show reproducable since it is behind a password. I'm not sure the best way to show that but here is the general gist.

I can get the form using the following

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- "http://probabilistic-footy.monash.edu/~footy/cgi-bin/presentTips.cgi.pl"
  
params <- list(
    name = user,
    passwd = pass,
    round = 8,
    comp = "normal")

sess <- httr::POST(present_tips_url, body = params,
                   encode = "form")
```

I can then extract the form like below.

```
form_unfilled <- httr::content(sess) %>%
  rvest::html_node("form") %>%
  rvest::html_form()
```

The form looks like this...

```
form_unfilled
#> <form> '<unnamed>' (POST /~footy/cgi-bin/processTips.cgi.pl)
#>   <input hidden> 'name': *
#>   <input hidden> 'passwd': *
#>   <input hidden> 'round': 8
#>   <input hidden> 'comp': normal
#>   <input radio> 'game1': home
#>   <input radio> 'game1': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame1': 1
#>   <input radio> 'game2': home
#>   <input radio> 'game2': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame2': 6
#>   <input radio> 'game3': home
#>   <input radio> 'game3': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame3': 4
#>   <input radio> 'game4': home
#>   <input radio> 'game4': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame4': 4
#>   <input radio> 'game5': home
#>   <input radio> 'game5': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame5': 20
#>   <input radio> 'game6': home
#>   <input radio> 'game6': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame6': 1
#>   <input radio> 'game7': home
#>   <input radio> 'game7': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame7': 2
#>   <input radio> 'game8': home
#>   <input radio> 'game8': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame8': 12
#>   <input radio> 'game9': home
#>   <input radio> 'game9': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame9': 7
#>   <input submit> '.submit':  Update Tips for Round 8 
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game9
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game4
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game3
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game6
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game5
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game1
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game2
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game8
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game7
```

So what I want to do is edit the value of the 'margin' fields and then submit them. I can do that fairly easily using `set_values()`

```
form_filled <- set_values(form_unfilled, margingame1 = 99)

form_filled
#> <form> '<unnamed>' (POST /~footy/cgi-bin/processTips.cgi.pl)
#>   <input hidden> 'name': *
#>   <input hidden> 'passwd': *
#>   <input hidden> 'round': 8
#>   <input hidden> 'comp': normal
#>   <input radio> 'game1': home
#>   <input radio> 'game1': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame1': 99
#>   <input radio> 'game2': home
#>   <input radio> 'game2': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame2': 6
#>   <input radio> 'game3': home
#>   <input radio> 'game3': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame3': 4
#>   <input radio> 'game4': home
#>   <input radio> 'game4': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame4': 4
#>   <input radio> 'game5': home
#>   <input radio> 'game5': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame5': 20
#>   <input radio> 'game6': home
#>   <input radio> 'game6': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame6': 1
#>   <input radio> 'game7': home
#>   <input radio> 'game7': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame7': 2
#>   <input radio> 'game8': home
#>   <input radio> 'game8': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame8': 12
#>   <input radio> 'game9': home
#>   <input radio> 'game9': away
#>   <input text> 'margingame9': 7
#>   <input submit> '.submit':  Update Tips for Round 8 
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game7
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game3
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game9
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game4
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game8
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game2
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game6
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game5
#>   <input hidden> '.cgifields': game1
```

However, when I try to submit this form with `submit_form` I get the following error.

```
submit_form(sess, form_filled)
#> Submitting with '.submit'
#> Error: object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable
```

I've also tried updating the *type* and *value* of the `.submit` field as per some other questions but this hasn't helped. I've also tried just submitted the original unfilled form and I get the same error.

```
form_filled$fields$.submit$type <- "submit"
form_filled$fields$.submit$value <- url
submit_form(sess, form_filled)
#> Submitting with '.submit'
#> Error: object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable

submit_form(sess, form_unfilled)
#> Submitting with '.submit'
#> Error: object of type 'externalptr' is not subsettable
```

If I do a traceback on that error I get the following

```
5: stopifnot(is.request(req), inherits(handle, "curl_handle"))
4: request_perform(req, hu$handle$handle)
3: httr::POST(url, x$config, ..., handle = x$handle)
2: request_POST(session, url = url, body = request$values, encode = request$encode, 
       ...)
1: submit_form(sess, form_unfilled)
```

Is anyone able to point me in a direction I could try here? I was wondering if it was because the radio button fields (e.g. `game1`) are repeated but I couldn't work out a way to remove them.